# circular base class dependency involving proj.web.domaincontext and proj.web.domaincontext

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to build this .web file it returns successful build, but when I run the project it returns the above error message, What I am missing

WHAT I HAVE DONE

I have changed from  "**UserControl x:Class="Demo1.Views.frmWardMaster**" "to  **UserControl x:Class="Demo1.frmWardMaster**", in my XAML file Views is a folder for my customization, I am attaching screen shot of solution explorer, any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

**UPDATE1**

even in visual studio forum, error exist and solution not found
[Check This](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735067/error-cs0146-circular-base-class-dependency-involving-when-compiling-silverlight-ria-solution)

[image]